# use JsLookup for multiple level array using play Json for lists with objects and simple lists

Tags: scala, play-json

i have a function that exctract from a json list of elements based on the path i give it.

the func looks like this:

```
def findAllValuesAtPath(jsValue: JsObject, path: String): List[JsValue] = {
    val jsPath = JsPath(path
      .split("\\[\\*]\\.")
      .flatMap(s => s.split("\\.")
        .map(RecursiveSearch)
      ).toList)
    jsPath(jsValue)
  }
```

for example:

```
{
  "person": {
    "kids": [
      {
        "name": "josh",
        "age": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "julia",
        "age": 13
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

now if i give the path - "person.kids[*].name" I will get list of their names `List("josh", "julia")` which its what i want.

but if the list of kids were just simple list like:

```
{
  "person": {
    "kids": [
      "josh",
      "julia"
    ]
  }
}
```

and i will give the path - "person.kids[*]" I will get empty list `List()` and I want to get this as `List("josh", "julia")` (without the brakets)

do you see any way to improve my func to handle both cases?